# The Receptionist Design Pattern (How to redirect to main thread?)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing

The Receptionist Pattern is a design pattern that provides a way to redirect an event from one thread to another thread for it to be processed. The magic of using Key-Value Observing (KVO). More info: [Receptionist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html)

I understand the concept and the code. What I am struggling with is understanding how to accomplish the following:

> "One common situation where the Receptionist pattern is useful is
>   key-value observing. In key-value observing, changes to the value of
>   an model object’s property are communicated to observers via KVO
>   notifications. However, changes to a model object can occur on a
>   background thread. This results in a thread mismatch, because changes
>   to a model object’s state typically result in updates to the user
>   interface, and these must occur on the main thread. In this case, you
>   want to redirect the KVO notifications to the main thread. where the
>   updates to an application’s user interface can occur."

Here is a snippet of what is described in the sample implementation.

> The client object supplies the block code that updates the user
>   interface when it creates a receptionist object, as shown in Listing
>   4-4. Note that when it creates the receptionist object, the client
>   passes in the operation queue on which the block is to be executed, in
>   this case the main operation queue.

```
RCReceptionist *receptionist = [RCReceptionist receptionistForKeyPath:@"value" object:model queue:mainQueue task:^(NSString *keyPath, id object, NSDictionary *change) {
    NSView *viewForModel = [modelToViewMap objectForKey:model];
    NSColor *newColor = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    [[[viewForModel subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setFillColor:newColor];
}];
```

Simply asked, how does one acquire the main operation queue (aka 'mainQueue') off the main thread? Can someone help me connect the dots here please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To grab the main operation queue:

```
[NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
```

Comment: Thank you...I was just reading the NSOperationQueue class reference. I really need to stop looking at this stuff at 2 am.